# Significado de [hora] *y pico*

Tags: expresiones, significado

> Te levantaste a las 6 y pico.

¿Esto quiere decir que la persona se levantó a las 6 y poco? ¿O también funcionaría si se levantó a las 6:40, por decir?

Comment: En Chile _pico_ es "pene". Acá diríamos _Te levantaste pasado las seis_.

Comment: @Rodrigo - ¿Se podría decir también "Te levantaste a las seis y algo"?  ¿Hasta qué hora es válido decir "Te levantaste pasado las seis"?

Comment: Se puede decir _a las seis y algo_, y se entiende bien, pero no me parece habitual. Y sobre lo segundo, no creo que haya una línea divisoria, pero las 6:40 son _pasado las seis y media, o casi las 7_. O sea, _pasado las 6_ se refiere a un arbitrario pero breve momento después de las 6, probablemente antes de la siguiente división en cuartos de una hora.

Comment: Interesante. Creí que esta era un expresión bastante difundida y parece que por el contrario en muchas partes no la usan. En Colombia es bastante frecuente pero solo se usa para expresar máximo 30 minutos. Ej Antes de las 6:30 sería 6 y pico. Después de 6:30 decimos 6 y media pasaditas pero si son "muy pasaditas" ya decimos _me levante casi a las 7_. 6:40 sería entonces **6 y 1/2 pasaditas**

Comment: @Rodrigo las _cuatro y tanto_, aunque ahora parece oírse menos.

Comment: @DGaleano juraría que en España también se usa (al menos, puedo afirmar que hace 50 años se usaba), y en Chile cuando la dice un extranjero se entiende perfectamente (aunque dependiendo de la situación pueden reírse o correr a explicarte que no lo digas así)

Answer (score 7):

Originariamente, el ***pico*** sí que representaba una cantidad pequeña, tal y como atestigua la acepción 9 de "pico":

> 9. m. Parte pequeña en que una cantidad excede a un número redondo.

Sin embargo, esta acepción evolucionó con el tiempo a la siguiente:

> 10. m. pico de una cantidad cuando se ignora cuál es o no se quiere expresar.

El ejemplo que pone para la acepción 9 es "1000 euros y 3 de pico". Sin embargo, de forma general usando la acepción 10 se puede decir "1000 euros y pico", y eso puede ser cualquier cantidad. Podrían ser 1245 euros, por poner, aunque esto se podría decir también que son "1200 euros y pico" (o también "1200 y pico euros").

Si el pico se acerca más al siguiente número redondo, aquí en España se puede decir que el pico es largo (no sé si esta expresión tendrá diferencias regionales). Así, en el caso de tu ejemplo se podría decir que "se levantó a las seis y pico largas", dado que la hora en punto más cercana es las siete en vez de las seis. Nótese que decimos "largas" porque el adjetivo afecta a la hora ("las seis") y no al pico.

Comment: +1. La verdad es que creo que he oído muy poco "las seis y pico **largas**", y en su lugar en mi entorno se favorecería "se levantó a las **siete menos algo**".

Comment: En mi entorno aun que el pico es un tiempo indeterminado, utilizar por ejemplo **las 6 y pico** haría referencia a una hora comprendida entre las 6:05 y las 6:40 aproximadamente y **las 6 y pico largas** entes las 6:30 y las 6:59**.

Answer (score -3):

En mi opinión, "y pico" hace alusión más bien a unas horas tardías, por ejemplo las 7:50.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Échale también un vistazo a otras preguntas y respuestas. Procura responder realmente a la pregunta y recuerda que el formato adecuado puede servir para hacer tu respuesta más fácil de leer y entender. No dudes en pedir ayuda si lo necesitas. Bienvenido de nuevo. ¡Espero seguir viendo contribuciones tuyas en el futuro!